# EV SSL-certificate on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl-certificate

Is it possible to use Extended Validation SSL-Certificate with Google App Engine for a custom domain?

**Edit 1:**
I didn't find EV-cert in the list of supported certs:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl#certificate_requirements

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, EV certs are [technically no different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate) then normal certs, so servers should have no problems using them. OTOH, here are [certificate requirements](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl#certificate_requirements) for use on GAE.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm actually asking. I didn't find EV certificate in the list of certificate types that App Engine supports. I would be very sad to buy one and reveal that it's not gonna work.